# Creating Schema Using nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Can Any Body Please Tell Me How We Are Create Schema Using nHibernate.Or Is It Possible Create Any Table Using nHibernate??

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Search for "SchemaExport". Details [here from nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide)

Comment: Also, if you are using FluentNHibernate, you might find this article useful: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Schema_generation

Answer (score 1):

It is [possible](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#M:NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute%28System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean%29) but there is a very limited use for this feature (initial rollout and integration tests). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7140214/625332).

```
new SchemaExport(_configuration).Execute(false, true, false);
```